# Transform ES2019 to React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been given the task of transforming ES2019 compiled React code back to JSX. The client lost their original files and I put my hand up to complete the task. Unfortunately, there are a few hundred files and as I go one by one transforming them, I thought there must be a way to compile them in one go to JSX.

For example a snippet of a file needed to transform may be...

```
import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/extends";
import React from 'react';
import { Item } from './Item';

const Container = props => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", _extends({}, props, {
    component: props.component || Item,
  }));
};

export default Container;
```

And I want to transform to...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Item } from './Item';

const Container = (props) => {
  return <div component={props.component || Item} />;
};

export default Container;
```

I know I can transform JSX to JS but how can I reverse this across hundreds of files?

Comment: Have you looked at `babel-js-to-jsx`?

Comment: @codemonkey. I have but just cannot get it to work.

Comment: It is a guess, but maybe if you have .map files you can generate back source files more easily (but I don't know if react build system generate them)

Comment: @Darren, would you be able to share what error you get when using `babel-js-to-jsx`?

Comment: @BogdanBiv. I believe it was an issue `Unexpected token`. However it was a while ago so cannot remember to entirety of the message. In the end, I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-createelement-to-jsx and the task was completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is apparently a babel plugin to do exactly what you ask. -> `babel-js-to-jsx`

Babel 6 plugin to convert from desugared React.DOM CallExpressions -> the equivalent JSX. Currently used to migrate to ES6+ from other compile to JS languages.

It can be used as a plugin:

```
require("babel-core").transform(code, {
  plugins: ["babel-transform-js-to-jsx", "syntax-jsx"],
}).code
```

Or from the command line for composition with other tools:

```
npm install babel-transform-js-to-jsx
cat example.ls | lsc -cb --no-header | js-to-jsx | esformatter -c format.json
```

[babel-js-to-jsx Documentation](https://github.com/JoeStanton/babel-transform-js-to-jsx)